# Regex for UNIX absolute path in python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to get UNIX absolute paths using the following regex:

```
"?[a-zA-Z0-9\/].*\.[a-zA-Z0-9].*"?
```

The problem is that this regex matchs:

```
"/home/user/web/other.longextension"
/path/to/file.php
```

And match this (unwanted) links:
    http://google.com
    https://web.com
    ftp://other.com

And does not match (wanted):
    '/path/to/any/file.txt'
    /this/path/too

Thanks

Comment: You don't mention the underlying problem, but can't you just check for the file or directory's existence? That doesn'give you all possible path names for non-existant files, but that may not be necessary.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using regex instead of `os.path` or `posixpath`?

Comment: I'm parsing the content of text file searching for absolute paths. The existence of the file or directory is not important.

Comment: A proper regex should also match `/home/you/My Documents` and `/home/me/뀋`. Strictly speaking, it should also tolerate control characters such as newlines and terminal control codes, but that's arguably borderline.

Comment: An absolute path begins with "/". Everything else is relative. Also, unix filenames can have just about every character, including spaces and other special characters, not just letters and numbers. Further, extensions are completely optional. Do you care about all those types of files (weird characters, no extension)? Can you be more specific about what you're trying to match?

Comment: Yes, the idea is to match any relative path:
/home/me/뀋
/home/me/file.php
/home/me/My Documents/

But exclude URLs as my current regex only matches files but doesn't match directories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
^['"]?(?:/[^/]+)*['"]?$
```

I put the quotes since you mentioned them in your question.

`[^/]+` is a negated class which matches all characters except forward slashes and with the `+` quantifier, it has to occur at least once.

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/iE3eJ4) with the samples you have in your question.

Comment: Thanks! Regex101 its a great resource.